# SetItemChecked(index,boolean) VS SetItemCheckState(index,Checkstate)

Tags: .net, checkedlistbox

I just stumbled upon the SetItemChecked and SetItemCheckState when working on a checked listbox.

The SetItemChecked takes an listindex and True/false to either set the listitem to checked or unchecked.

The SetItemCheckState takes an listindex and a CheckState-enum to set the state to either checked, unchecked or Indeterminate.

Why does SetItemChecked exists, when SetItemCheckState does cover all states?

Is it just to make it easy to use a boolean because its the most common use to check/uncheck or has I missed something?

And if it just to make it easier to use a boolean, why not have that as an overload to the function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no real difference. SetItemCheck calls SetItemCheckedState like so:

```
public void SetItemChecked(int index, bool value)
{
    this.SetItemCheckState(index, value ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked);
}
```

Like you've already assumed, I guess it's just a helper-method to make things simpler for the developer.

Comment: I wonder why they did not use ONE name for the method, overloaded with either type of argument. Clean AND easy for the developer... IMHO

Answer (score 2):

I vote for

> Is it just to make it easy to use a boolean because its the most common use to check/uncheck or has I missed something?

But the extra function will normally wont be used (only the Indeterminate case is added)

EDIT:
CheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(1, CheckState.Checked) is horrible to read (but clear)
CheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(1, true) is easier to read

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is much more common to want to check/uncheck depending on a boolean value, and to avoid having to do this:

`listbox.SetItemCheckState(i, value ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.UnChecked)`

all the time. Also, it is not an overload because is mirrors the Checked and CheckState properties of the CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear but surprisingly noone mentioned it here:

With `.SetItemChecked()` you can only check or uncheck an item while you can also set item checked state to 'Indeterminate' by `.SetItemCheckState()` which will provide a shaded checkbox on item when using 3D checkboxes.